# Send two pictures to python flask api by restTemplate

Tags: java, python, spring, flask

I get problem with my python api it doesn't receive à picture from my spring boot api.

i think the problem come from my spring api because when i send my files by postman to my python api i get the good answer.

thank you in advance

```
        /** 
         * headers
         */
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        /**
         * body
         */
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("photoAVerifier",new InputStreamResource(photoAVerifier.getInputStream(), photoAVerifier.getOriginalFilename()));
        body.add("photoProfil",new InputStreamResource(photoAVerifier.getInputStream(),photoAVerifier.getOriginalFilename()));
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
          = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        /**
         * request
         */
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<ReponseApi> response = restTemplate
        .exchange(urlApiCheckPhoto,HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ReponseApi.class);
```

Comment: I see a typo "ReponseApi". should that be "ResponseApi"?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile thank you but is not mistake i called my class like that.